# Change Display Order of 2 Column in Mobile View

Tags: html, css, sass

Hello I'm new to web development, I ask for your help/advice. I created this 2 columns (Item 1 is a image and Item 2 is a text), On mobile view I want it to change its order so that the (Item 2 will be on top and Item 1 will be below), I have tried the flex-wrap: reverse; but I want to know if there is a posible way with the code that I have made.

Thank you in Advance! sorry for this Question. I'm just trying to find another way. Arigato Gozaimazu!!!

here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/w2ybd7ax/

for the code,

HTML:

```
<div class="grid__items">
            <div class="item__1">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/457x262" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="item__2">
                <h2>Block Heading</h2>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.grid__items {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        font-size: 0;

        .item__1 {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 43%;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin: 0% 0 1% 0%;

            &.second-grid {
                width: 43%;
                margin: 0% 0 1% 3%;
            }

            img {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        .item__2 {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 54%;
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0% 0 1% 3%;

            &.second-grid {
                width: 54%;
                margin: 0% 0 1% 0%;
            }

            h2 {
              margin-top: 0;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                font-size: 20px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: 0.025em;
            }

            p {
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 1.94;
                letter-spacing: 0.025em;
            }
        }

    }



   @media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:767px) {
        .grid__items {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            letter-spacing: 0;
            font-size: 0;

            .item__1 {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                vertical-align: top;
                margin: 0% 0 5% 0%;

                &.second-grid {
                    width: 100%;
                    margin: 0% 0 1% 0%;
                }

                img {
                    width: 100%;
                }
            }

            .item__2 {
                margin: 0 auto;
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                margin: 0% 0 1% 0%;

                &.second-grid {
                    width: 100%;
                    margin: 0% 0 1% 0%;
                }

                h2 {
                    margin-bottom: 10px;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    font-weight: 600;
                    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
                }

                p {
                    font-size: 16px;
                    line-height: 1.94;
                    letter-spacing: 0.025em;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `order` property & `flex-direction:column`? Could be a solution for you? I think that Flexbox is what you are looking for.

Comment: Konichiwa! I have tried that method that you suggest but I just want to know if there is a other posible way to do it with the code that I wrote.